# Startup issue / question mark folder

Tags: mac

My MacBook Air has been showing me the question mark folder ONLY when I close it. I reset the NVRAM and nothing changed. If I turn my mac off while it remains open, it’s fine. If I let my mac sleep while it remains open, its  fine. The only problem is when I physically close my mac, as soon as I open it again I have the question mark folder. Then I need to restart my mac like 3 times for it to work again. Any suggestions?

Comment: **If** this really only occurs when the lid is closed, then it could be due to some loose connections that are impacted when the lid is closed. However, this is just a guess and without looking at the machine it will be very hard to tell.